# Screen pitch black after random shudown, Gpu's fans full speed.

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, gpu, fan

This morning I went to  power up my pc and BAM. My screen is pitch black.
Noticed that Gpu's fans were at full speed. Switched to my moba gpu and well, it works fine.

I cant understand if it's a GPU or PSU problem, possible that my GPU fried overnight after less than 1 year?

GPU is a gtx 760x
PSU is an Antec HCG 520 (520W)
Moba is an Asus b85 plus

Comment: A GPU can 'fry' any time- after a day, a year or more. From what you describe it is likely to be a GPU problem, but it may be worth checking the event viewer logs: either press `<windows key>+r` and type 'eventvwr.msc' and hit enter, or find it by right-clicking on the start button

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely a GPU problem, and yes it is possible it could have failed.  A PSU problem cannot cause a GPU to run faster/hotter. It may have just defaulted to full fan speed due to the failure. You found that your monitor still works fine. You can try looking in Device Manager for the GPU device. Also try updating the driver. These may help you learn more. You can also try installing it into a different computer to see that it was for sure the GPU. It would be interesting if the Event Logs have any info as bertieb suggested.

Now it is possible for something connected to the GPU to cause the GPU failure (PSU, motherboard), but I doubt it in your case since everything else is working ok. The only way to know is to get another relatively high powered GPU in there. Bottom-line, I'm guessing it's the GPU and only the GPU.